# Why isn't the 2nd material showing up?

Tags: unity-game-engine, 3d, maya

I have created an object in Maya and imported it in Unity. The mesh for this object has 2 materials. Normally, it works properly, both in Scene View and Play Mode.

After I installed the HDRender Pipeline package, I get the following issue: 
- In Scene View, I can properly see both materials. 
- When I click "Play" however, the 2nd material from the mesh disappears. It even disappears from the model preview. If I click "Stop" it reverts to normal.

Any idea why this is happening?

[image]
[image]